# MySQL on two ports using IPTables - self-access

Tags: mysql, linux, firewall, iptables, ports

I'm trying to make MySQL available by 2 ports: 3306 and 3339
I added rule to iptables:

> iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i bond0 -p tcp --dport 3339 -j REDIRECT
>   --to-port 3306

and everythin is great for remote connections.
But if I'm trying to connect it locally, I'm getting an error:

```
mysql -u username -ppassword --port=3339 -h Host.Name
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'Host.Name' (111)
```

Any ideas how can I edit iptables to get local access via 3339 port?

Comment: couldn't you just use 3306 for local connections? Any way I don't understand what you're trying to achieve by pointing 2 external ports to the same mysql instance

Comment: Unfortunately no, I need same MySQL on two different ports. That's for tungsten replication scheme from the behind NAT.

Answer (score 2):

Since PREROUTING isn't used by the loopback interface we have to add one more rule:

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -o lo --dport 3339 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3306
```